# Наследование от object и от других встроенных типов

Tags: python

Узнав о такой штуке как наследование от внутренних типов, я задался вопросом - "А зачем это, собственно говоря, надо?" Ну, допустим, создашь ты класс от 'list', и что ты с ним можешь делать? Разве что append() использовать, да и как в этот экземпляр добавить сразу несколько чисел, если append принимает только одно значение? Не проще ли создать обычную переменную?

Answer (score 1):

переопределить вывод (преобразование в строку `__str__`), потому что я хочу чтобы вывод был какой-нибудь нестандартный

добавление нового функционала с сохранением старого, делать это через создание нового типа и включение старого как элемента зачастую неудобно

да даже например я хочу работать со списками как с векторами (привет языку `R`) - значит для меня сложение двух списков должно означать не увеличение размера списка, а сложение его элементов с сохранением размера

и т.д.

можно придумать очень много применений к наследованию от стандартных типов